# .NET 4.0 Add same values in all rows for a column in DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, .net-4.0

I have following DataTable

```
DataTable dt = new dataTable();
```

I have got this dataTable filled from some another method. It will have 50000 rows and 40 columns before executing following statements.

Number of rows and columns may vary. hence I have not defined specific set of columns to the dataTable.

I want to add two columns at the end (guid and addeddate) and want to add same value in all 50K rows  for those 2 columns.

I have written simple foreach loop for this. Is there any way that I can do it Parallely?

I tried using Parallel.Foreach but didnt get any success.

```
//by this time my dt will have 50000 rows and 40 columns

dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("guid", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("addeddate", typeof(DateTime)));
string sessionIDValue = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());
DateTime todayDt = DateTime.Today;                   


foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    row["guid"] = sessionIDValue;
    row["addeddate"] = todayDt;     
}
```

Comment: Did you already try specifying the `DefaultValue` for the DataColumns you are adding? I wouldn't dare to predict how well this performs (if it even works).

Comment: @Filburt yes, but as the structure of DataTable is not fixed, we cant provide that

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the rows using explicit indexes, and the row index would be a perfect way to do this.

You should be able to create an array equal to the number of rows you have (e.g. 50000) with an index for each row as the values of that array (e.g. 0..1..2..3.. and so on), and then use a parallel loop on that array of indexes whereby you're passing in the explicit row index to your dt.Rows object.

The gist of the code would be:

```
// Pseudo code

// Create array equal to size of the # of rows (int ArrayOfIndexes[])
// Fill that array with values representing row indexes starting at 0

Parallel.ForEach(ArrayOfIndexes, (index) => 
{
    lock(dt)
    {
        dt.Rows[index]["guid"] = sessionIDValue;
        dt.Rows[index]["addeddate"] = todayDt;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: I did find out that since DataTable isn't thread-safe, that you have to include the lock around your assignments, which obviously yields a performance hit, but should still be faster than simply looping through without the Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: I think it doesn't make sense to use lock here. And even if you wanted to do so, the best practice is to have a separate lockObject. +1 for Parallel.ForEach

Comment: The "lock" was to protect against the fact that you'll get intermittent errors during row value assignment since DataTable isn't thread-safe.  Agreed with you that separate lock object is a good idea...  I was basically just giving the "essence" of the solution, not the exact solution.   :)

Answer (score 0):

An upgrade of @Shane Oborn 's answer without extra variable of ArrayOfIndexes and uses separate lock object.

I would use:

```
var lockObj = new object();
Parallel.Foreach(dt.AsEnumerable(), row =>
{
    lock(lockObj)
    {
        row["guid"] = sessionIDValue;
        row["addeddate"] = todayDt;     
    }
});
```

You have to add using statements:

```
using System.Data.DataSetExtensions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
```

Comment: This isn't true Anton.  As I mentioned above, if you use what you have here, and then try this on an array of let's say size 5000, you will see that you get "index" errors due to DataTable not being thread-safe.

Comment: I've tested and you are right, seems it is not possible to edit DataTable in parallel without a lock. And the lock removes all benefits of parallelism in this case ...

Comment: Correct, if the code above is ultimately all that is used, then there would be no benefit.  However, if there is anything else going on that could be outside the lock, obviously in that case some benefit arises but only relative to the amount of work being done outside the lock.

Comment: Yes, like checking some ip from column1 and setting status in column2